# merge 20 clips of avi files

Tags: opencv, video

I have 20 clips http://www.ee.cuhk.edu.hk/~xgwang/MITtraffic.html, (I think it's a famous dataset)Anybody know which tool I could use to merge them together, I am open to java or cpp or python. I see openCV, but could not find a suitable solution. Anybody any suggestions? Or if other way to merge these 20 clips? with many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/292223-Join-or-Combine-2-AVI-files-with-no-quality-loss

They recommended:

> AVI Demux. Load the first, append the second, save the result (don't forget to put the extension on the filename when you save). If you are asked if you want to use smart rendering answer yes, and use a quantizer value of 2. This works for me.

**EDIT** - If you are open to other softwares and is only a one time process :) All the best

Comment: thanks, it could work and solve my problem. I once thought to do this with code....